# XPathEvalError: Unregistered function for matches() in lxml

Tags: python, xpath, lxml, xpath-2.0

i am trying to use the following xpath query in python

```
from lxml.html.soupparser import fromstring
root = fromstring(inString)
nodes = root.xpath(".//p3[matches(.,'ABC')]//preceding::p2//p3")
```

but it gives me the error

```
  nodes = root.xpath(".//p3[matches(.,'ABC')]//preceding::p2//p3")
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 1507, in lxml.etree._Element.xpath (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:52198)
  File "xpath.pxi", line 307, in lxml.etree.XPathElementEvaluator.__call__ (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:152124)
  File "xpath.pxi", line 227, in lxml.etree._XPathEvaluatorBase._handle_result (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:151097)
  File "xpath.pxi", line 212, in lxml.etree._XPathEvaluatorBase._raise_eval_error (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:150896)
  lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Unregistered function
```

how can i use XPath 2.0 functions here with lxml?

**Clarification**

I was using the contains function earlier as

```
nodes = root.xpath(".//p3[contains(text(),'ABC')]//preceding::p2//p3")
```

problem is that my xml has newlines and whitespaces in the text, hence i tried using something like

```
nodes = root.xpath(".//p3[contains(normalize-space(),'ABC')]//preceding::p2//p3")
```

but this has no effect. Finally i tried to use the matches function and i got the error.

**Sample XML**

```
<doc>

<q></q>

<p1>
    <p2 dd="ert" ji="pp">

        <p3>1</p3>
        <p3>2</p3>
        <p3>
               ABC
        </p3>
        <p3>3</p3>

     </p2>

     <p2 dd="ert" ji="pp">

        <p3>4</p3>
        <p3>5</p3>
        <p3>ABC</p3>
        <p3>6</p3>

     </p2>

</p1>
<r></r>
<p1>
    <p2 dd="ert" ji="pp">

        <p3>7</p3>
        <p3>8</p3>
        <p3>ABC
        </p3>
        <p3>9</p3>

     </p2>

     <p2 dd="ert" ji="pp">

        <p3>10</p3>
        <p3>11</p3>
        <p3>ABC</p3>
        <p3>12</p3>

     </p2>

</p1>
</doc>
```

Comment: Could you please provide us with an example XML demonstrating the problem? Thanks!

Comment: sure, please see the update

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As mentioned in the other answer, emphasizing on the other part of the quoted documentation, you can use EXSLT extensions to have a regex [`match()`](http://exslt.org/regexp/functions/match/) function with lxml, for example :

```
......
ns = {"re": "http://exslt.org/regular-expressions"}
nodes = root.xpath(".//p3[re:match(.,'ABC')]//preceding::p2//p3", namespaces=ns)
```

Comment: great! thanks. can i make the xpath query optional? meaning if there is a <p2> which does not have either <p3>ABC</p3> or <p3>XYZ</p3>, then i still want all of the <p3>s in that <p2>

Answer (score 4):

> how can i use XPath 2.0 functions here with lxml?

You cannot ([reference](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html)):

> **lxml supports XPath 1.0**, XSLT 1.0 and the EXSLT extensions through libxml2 and libxslt in a standards compliant way.

[`contains()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/contains) is probably the closest you can go in this case:

```
.//p3[contains(., 'ABC')]//preceding::p2//p3
```

Comment: correct, i was using contains earlier but my xml text has CRs and LFs in the text so i was not able to properly select the node. hence i was hoping for something like matches