# Evaluate Xpath2.0 in python

Tags: python, xpath, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

I have an XPath expression as shown below.

```
if(replace(//p[1]/text(),'H','h') = 'hello') then //p[1]/text() else if(//p[1]/text() = 'world') then //p[2]/text() else 'notFound'
```

I want to display which 'if ' expression worked.

```
e.g //p[1]/text() if first 'if' expression worked.
```

'If' expression can have nested if, for loops and xpath2.0 functions.

I can't find any xpath2.0 library for python. So I tried to convert this Js [library](https://github.com/ilinsky/jquery-xpath) to python still I can able to split xpath2.0 expression to lexers but can't convert it fully to python.

Suggest me some Xpath2.0 library for python, if available.
Also how to interpret XPath expression and display which part of the expression worked?

Comment: https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#xpath is a fine library, or simply https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support

Comment: Ya i tried it. It supports only xpath1.0 expression and I extend it to support xpath 2.0 functions like replace, tokenize but 'if' and 'for' expression can't be evaluated.

Comment: Saxon 9.8 supports XPath 3 and 2 and is available in a Saxon/C version at http://saxonica.com/download/c.xml, so as other libraries for Python are written in C it might be possible to build one for Python based on Saxon/C, at least for XPath 2/3 evaluation, not sure how far you would get to dig into the XPath implementation.

Answer (score 14):

As you already know, [lxml](https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html), the cornerstone of Python's XML/XPath support, features only

> XPath 1.0, XSLT 1.0 and the EXSLT extensions through libxml2 and libxslt

We still have some options.

I researched this topic recently (specifically, Python's XQuery support).
See the W3C for a reference list of [XML Query Implementations](http://w3.org/XML/Query/#implementations).

1. Python Modules with XPath 2+ and EXSLT Extensions (e.g. an [EXSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34047567/xpathevalerror-unregistered-function-for-matches-in-lxml) for regex [match](http://exslt.org/regexp/functions/match/)ing)
   There are [some modules on PiPy](https://pypi.org/search/?q=%22xpath%202.0%22) that partially offer XPath 2.0+ functionality.
2. There are some OSS XML/NoSQL-DBMS that implement XPath/XQuery 2.0 functions, e.g.

   - [Zorba](http://www.zorba-xquery.com/), an open source portable embeddable C++ implementation of XQuery 1.0/2.0 which has Python bindings (this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133648/xquery-library-under-python) has some pointers),
   - as well as [Sedna](https://github.com/bitkeeper/zif.sedna) and some commercial DBMS. Depending on your project, this could be a good choice.
3. I believe [Saxon/C](http://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/index.xml) (by [Michael Kay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/415448/michael-kay)) with Cython is the most promising road.
   It was tried before using [Boost.Python](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/python/doc/html/index.html) and at [pysaxon](https://github.com/ajelenak/pysaxon).
   **Update**: A [Saxon/C extension for Python 3](http://saxonica.com/saxon-c/index.xml) has been published meanwhile.
4. You could use a subprocess to call a CLI XML processor (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40167794/8291949)), e.g. `subprocess.call(["saxon", "-o:output.xml", "-s:file.xml", "file.xslt"])`
5. Another option is using [XSLT](https://gist.github.com/lawlesst/3370069)/XPath/XQuery with saxon and/or other [Java XML classes](https://wiki.python.org/jython/XmlRelatedExamples) in [Jython](http://www.jython.org/).
6. Finally, you could set-up a web service that does the hard work for you in a language like Java, .NET, etc, that comes with proper XPath 3+ support (also suggested by Kay [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29444576/8291949)).

Still somewhat disappointing, especially for a big language like Python.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by Martin we have a Saxon product for C/C++/PHP languages, called Saxon/C which out for a few years now. We have been seeing users interested in using Saxon/C with Python.

**Update 2019** A Saxon/C extension for Python3 has now been released : [SaxonC - XML document processing for C/C++, PHP and Python](https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/index.xml)

One user has successfully used Boost.Python to interface with our C++ library. 
Another user has done the interfacing in a different way: https://github.com/ajelenak/pysaxon

Comment: An official Saxon/C interface for Python would be awesome.

Comment: We have now release an Saxon/C extension for Python3: http://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/index.xml